Unexpected behaviour on RaspberryPi OS lite (Debian based )
I was building a custom image and started with the lite version and installed lxde on top as well as other things to run a .NET server and chromium browser... But here is the thing, I keep getting some weird issues after I flash it into an SD card that I'm thinking it could be due instability of the OS.
Issues being, some services not starting like wpa_supplicant
Not logging in after I enter the right username and password.
When i switch to terminal and interface, I get different programs showing not found like: vi, reboot, shutdown, systemctl, which ... Programs that come usually préinstalled yet it shows not found.
For ex with "vi" I can find it in /usr/bin/vi yet I can't run it with full path neither.
Any idea on what could be the issue ? Is this an OS problem ?

My bets are on the storage device on this. It's probably a cheap SD card; and these are error-prone. If an executable file seems to be there and can't be executed, then chances are there's trouble with reading it. Does this happen with other SD cards as well?

I haven't tried with another one... But it seems so strange

It's the most likely component for sporadic failure. So, really, try with a different SD card.
